# Writing an OS kernel in assembly with NASM

Tags: assembly, kernel, nasm

I want to know what is the standard way for writing a -simple- kernel to be compiled on NASM?

To get it clearer:
I was able to define the code block with **all** the following ways:

```
[segment code]
[segment .code]
segment code
segment .code

[section code]
[section .code]
section code
section .code
```

I need to know what is the standard way to do that, And what is the difference between them...

Thanks

Comment: NASM has [excellent documentation](http://www.nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc6.html#section-6.3). What part of that are you having trouble understanding? You are more likely to get answers here with a more specific question.

Comment: Do you really mean *"kernel"* ? Or do you just mean a simple *program* ?

Comment: I mean a kernel to be booted (instead of current OS..)

Comment: in that case you have a *long* road ahead of you - I suggest you start by studying the Linux kernel sources - you can learn a lot that way.

Comment: check this out http://www.brokenthorn.com/Resources/

Answer (score 3):

Your question is answer in the NASM documentation, as stated above.

The truth is.. the sections do not mean verymuch when you load your code. A kernel to be loaded, needs a complete bootloader, and a bootloader has 512b to load GDTr, , enabling A20, entering protected mode, and jumping to _kmain.
Checkout OSDev.org for more examples, and information.